# Hide specific "undefined function XXX" in intelephense

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intelephense

Is there any way to prevent specific functions to show the "undefined function XXX" message? I have an old PHP project in docker and it's confusing seeing all the error messages refering to the same 2-3 functions: [image]

I have tried adding the specific php version (`{"intelephense.environment.phpVersion": "5.6"}`) to the settings.json file but it has no effect.

I also tried adding `{"intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedFunctions": true}` but that hides all the messages but that is not what I want.

Comment: Only way probably is to define those functions somewhere inside that project directly like an "interface".

Comment: As the `mysql_` functions were removed from PHP in version 7, and were deprecated for years before that, what is the reason for not just removing them from the code?

Comment: The code runs in a PHP 5.6 version, and for now there is not intention to upgrade PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach is to create a stub file (e.g. `phpstubs/mysql.php`)

```
<?php
function mysql_escape_string($str){}
```

Then add this folder (`phpstubs`) to this setting: `Intelephense> Environment: Include Paths`

---

Another option is using the `@disregard` annotation.

```
/** @disregard */
$str2 = mysql_escape_string($str1);
```

Comment: The stub file option works like a charm and it's not as invasive as the @disregard option