# Intelephense from complaining about an undefined method on concrete interface implementation

Tags: php, symfony, visual-studio-code, intelephense

In my Symfony 7.0.3 project, I have a custom OAuth2 authenticator that uses `League\Oauth2` by way of `knpuniversity/oauth-client-bundle`.

In my social authenticator class, I call `$oauthUser = $client->fetchUserFromToken($accessToken)`.  The return type from that method is `ResourceOwnerInterface`, which is implemented by `GoogleUser` - the class of the returned object.

The annoyance I'm having now is that when I write `$oauthUser->getEmail()`, intelephense complains that `getEmail` is an undefined method.  It's not, of course, and the code runs just fine.

Is there anything I can do in code or editor configuration (I'm using Visual Studio Code) to prevent those red squiggly lines?

I had the same problem in my controllers calling `$this->getUser()` which I solved by overloading `getUser()` with a concrete return type.  I'm not sure overloading is possible here though.

Thanks.

Comment: You should add all these projects in one workspace, or add them into the include path, see: [Hide specific "undefined function XXX" in intelephense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77886077/hide-specific-undefined-function-xxx-in-intelephense)